# Understanding Nested functions in python

Tags: python

I am new in stackflow. I will so thankful if someone can help me.

I have to resolve this:

Define a nested function called nested_sum, where in the first part of the function you accept an argument called x, and in the second part (the function inside) you take another argument called y. In the function inside you have to calculate the sum of x and y.

To test your function create a variable called `res_1` where you pass the `x` argument to `nested_sum`, and then create a variable called `res_2` where you pass the `y` argument of the `res_1` variable to get the final solution.

Have `x` equal 2 for `res_1` and y equal 10 for `res_2`.

After looking on the internet I found a similar code, but I don't really understand how it works!

```
def nested_sum(x):
    def in_sum(y):
        return x+y
    return in_sum

res_1 = nested_sum(2)
res_2 = res_1(10)
```

Thank you

Comment: If you got your answer, please mark one as accepted clicking huge checkbox near it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to realise `res_1` is simply the `in_sum()` function.

Therefore as per your code:

`nested_sum(2)` puts `x = 2` and then returns the `in_sum()` function.
`res_2 = res_1(10) = in_sum(10)`

Therefore `x = 2` and `y = 10`, so thus

`x + y = 2 + 10 = 12`

Answer (score 0):

You can write the code (easier to understand) as follows:

```
def nested_sum(x):
    def in_sum(y):
        return x+y
    return in_sum



res_1 = nested_sum(2) #nested_sum return in_sum(y) location with x=2 so --> res_1= in_sum (2+y)
res_2 = res_1(10)     #Cause res_1 points in_sum(2+y) res2=in_sum(2+10)=12
```

Comment: Thank so much. It is means that assigning a variable the result of a nested function the inner functions are methods of this variable?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, function in Python is an object. Think of it as a piece of paper where it is written what arguments it needs an what to do with them.

`nested_sum(2)` creates a new piece of paper where it is writen: «take the  argument, add 2 to and return it.»

`nested_sum()` creates a new piece of paper where it is writen: «take the  argument, add  and return it.»

Let me rename variables in your code:

```
def increaser_function_maker(x):

    def the_new_function(y):
        return x + y

    return the_new_function

function_that_takes_number_and_adds_two_to_it = increaser_function_maker(2)
result = function_that_takes_number_and_adds_two_to_it(10)
```

There is another way to make this function. Maybe it will be easier to understand:

```
def increaser_function_maker(value_to_add):
    return lambda i: i + value_to_add
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand better from all answers.