# what is a function inside a function in django/python

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

I wanna know, what is main idea function inside a function in djanggo?, something like this example.

```
def partition_by_mod(base):
    def func(n):
        return n % base
    return staticmethod(func)
```

when I call this function like this test = partition_by_mod(8), so I'm wondering where the "n" comes from.

thank you ~

Comment: The `n` comes from you. And you haven't shown that part yet. What do you do with `test` now that you have it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding Nested functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546421/understanding-nested-functions-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

> what is main idea function inside a function in djanggo?

It's the same as a function defined anywhere else, but it is accessible *by name* only within the outer function, and it closes over the variables (such as `base`) of the scope in which it is defined, so that they are indirectly accessible to whomever calls the function.  Your particular example could be replaced by a lambda:

```
def partition_by_mod(base):
    return staticmethod(lambda n: n % base)
```

> when I call this function like this test = partition_by_mod(8), so I'm wondering where the "n" comes from.

The argument is provided by the code that actually calls the function.  Note in particular that

> ```
>     staticmethod(func)
> ```

does not *call* `func`, but rather passes `func` itself as an argument, presumably with the idea that `staticmethod` will call it.  This is sometimes described as a "callback function".  You can recognize a function call by the parenthesized argument list, which is required even when there are zero arguments. If and when `staticmethod` does call it, `staticmethod` has the responsibility to provide the needed argument.

Comment: Halo John  thankyou for your answer :) i really appreciate it.

so, how can i call stacimethod from return the function?

i tried to call function like this -> halo = partition_by_mod(8)
print(halo.(80)) and i got the result "invalid syntax"

Comment: @DennySugianto, `partition_by_mod()` calls `staticmethod()` itself (note the parenthesized argument list after its name) and returns the return value of that call.  There's no particular reason to think that the return value provides a way to call `staticmethod()` again, and my best guess would be that you don't, in fact, actually want to do that.